# convert longitude and latitude to x,y based location

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-maps

Based on Instructions on [how to display and clear a route on a map by using a location document](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11944/CS_determining_a_route_using_getRoute_893347_11.jsp)

the routing use x,y Based Location.

my question : how to convert longitude and latitude to x,y based location to be able to use them to route in BB maps.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The X and Y values in the location document specified by your link are latitude and longitude respectively in degrees multiplied by 10,000.